# iPhone: what is mean Landscape?

Tags: iphone

hi what is Landscape and where we use in our app's

Comment: Get an iPhone, learn to use it, then come back and start developing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Landscape means holding the phone so that the longer edge is horizontal.

[image]

The opposite to landscape is called portrait.

[image]

If you want your application to work well when the user rotates the phone you need to design your user interface so that it display well in both landscape and portrait modes.

Comment: Wow, that's a _much_ better picture than my meagre effort. +1 :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Sexy graphics are interesting, but ascii art is beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Lanscape and Protrait - are device orientation. In landscape mode we have 480x320 resolution and Portrait resolution is vice versa - 320x480