# iPhone : How to calculate pixel size from given inch size for image?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, size, pixel

I having image size in inch and i have to calculate pixel equivallent for that size for that what i have to do?

Suppose Given size for image in  is : 7X5 inch
than what is the pixel size for the image.

Comment: Do you know the PPI (pixels per inch) of the image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610193/calculating-pixel-size-on-an-iphone...visit this post..

Answer (score 0):

It's base on your **dpi (Dots per Inch)**

I assume you scan the image 7x5 from scanner with 100dpi

so, the resolution will be width x dpi : height x dpi = 700 x 500

You can see also [Inches to Pixels Converter](http://www.louisedade.co.uk/apps/pixels-to-inches-converter)