# How to convert coordinates from inches to pixel?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am getting positions/coordinates(x and y values)from server in inches. How to convert from inches to pixel which is support to retina and without retina. Please help me.

```
float x= 0.916667;
float Y= 7.885417

float deltaX = x * 72;
float deltaY = y * 72;

UIActivityIndicatorView *avtivity=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(deltaX, deltaY, 20, 20)];
[avtivity startAnimating];
avtivity.activityIndicatorViewStyle=UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
[imgView addSubview:avtivity];
```

[image]

I need to display ActivityIndicatorView on the top off START button in the above screen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610193/calculating-pixel-size-on-an-iphone

Comment: Why do you assume that iOS is 72 ppi?  In fact it is not, and in fact many iOS devices are different.  What is your goal here anyway?  7 inches will be off the screen of *any* Apple phone device.

Comment: According to iphone5 i need to do float deltaX = x * 325.97;
float deltaY = y * 325.97; based on formula inches*dpi=pixel. But the activity is showing some where.

Comment: I repeat:  Look at your Y value!!  Nearly 8 inches.  You expect it to stay on screen with that kind of offset?

Comment: No, I just want to display activity indicator on the start button

Answer (score 2):

you should be using resolution independent points... points are 12 to a pica, which are 6 to an inch, so 1:72.

from points to inches: f(x) = x/72

the reverse, inches to points: f(x) = x*72

Comment: Thank you for reply, It doesn't work for me. Ex: i am getting y position y = 7.88542 inches. if i do 7.88542*72=567.75, the vies is going to out. There is half off difference between original to this.

Comment: i am not sure that I follow... what does "the vies is going to out" mean?

Comment: i need to show small view on the main view with the help of coordinates which is getting from server. When applied these coordinates to small view it is not placing exactly.

Comment: can you give a small example in code?

Comment: I have updated question with some code. Please have a look.